# Using cookies to store session in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session-state

Storing the entire session in a cookie has been standard in Rails for the last few years - is there an easy way to achieve something similar with ASP MVC?

By default, anything in Session / TempData is stored in memory on the server. In web.config this can be changed to an SQL Store / server-side cache. I'd like to be able to have these objects persisted in a cookie.

It looks like I could implement a custom Session-State Store Provider. Is there a simpler approach?

Comment: Did you mean to type 'entire session in a cookie'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, implement a [custom state session-provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587.aspx). And no, afaik there isn't a simpler approach.

Ps. it isn't as bad as it looks i.e. > half of the [odbc sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178589.aspx) is writing to the db.

Comment: Following up on this, I implemented a custom state session-provider & it was indeed straightforward.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

I think it would be much more efficient to just store the session ID (a hash or whatever) in the cookie, and then use that ID to get the session data from memory / database / whatever storage you prefer. Keeping the full session state in a cookie increases bandwidth innecessarily.

Also, keep security in mind: if the cookie contains authentication information or other sensitive data and you're not careful, it can easily be hacked by the user to gain privileges or otherwise mess with your application (encrypting the data sucks too, because then you have to base-64 encode the encrypted data, which further wastes bandwidth and processing time). You should *never* trust input from the user.

Comment: Would a custom session-state store be necessary in this case or would it just make sense to disable session in the web.config?

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly discourage storing the entire session in cookies. It has bad performance implications. Consider this: every request (to every resource) will contain an overhead of possibly stale data that you only need once or twice. Eventually this overhead will hit your users, your bandwidth and your site performance.

Here's an example:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
OtherUsefulHeaders: foo
Cookie: YourSessionState=...
```

Initial request size is around 200 bytes. Let's say, you add around 100 bytes to your session. Now the size is 300 bytes and overhead is ~30%. You add another 100 bytes, and overhead is 50%. Which means it roughly requires 2x time to send the request and 2x bandwidth.

You should rather look into [cookie-based TempData implementation](https://blogs.msmvps.com/luisabreu/blog/2009/03/23/the-mvc-framework-maintaining-tempdata-on-cookies/) as it has much smaller footprint and actually makes sense.

Comment: How would maintaining the session information through TempData (implemented through a cookie store) be any faster? There's also the additional code overhead of maintaining that TempData.

A session should be fairly light - in our case it's a few dozen bytes - so the overhead of the request should be minimal.

A cookie based session store was adopted as standard in Rails in 2007. This article discusses why they made that move.

http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2007/2/21/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-cookie-based-sessions

Comment: I'm very happy for the Rails community, but my point is based on statistical data: http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/03/01/performance-research-part-3/. TempData is advantageous over session in that its overhead applies only once -- during a page roundtrip. Otherwise the cookies should be clean.
Anyway, after a bitter experience in a web-farm scenario I don't use Session at all, it's not worth it.

Comment: what method are you using now for session state? I would have thought the session object (whether inproc or not) or a cookie are the only choices?

Comment: @UpTheCreek - I write code that doesn't rely on session state. Every piece of information can be either rebuilt from the request (including cookies) or stored in the cache/db (if it's expensive to re-calculate).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend storing `TempData` in the cookie (as opposed to the entire session).

In order to store `TempData` in the cookie, you need to override `ITempDataProvider` and implement your own custom provider.

There is actually a nuget package available (which does this custom implementation for you): [BrockAllen.CookieTempData](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BrockAllen.CookieTempData.dll/) and  [here is the documentation](https://brockallen.com/2012/06/11/cookie-based-tempdata-provider/). The good thing about this package is that it both compress and encrypts your `TempData`, so you don't need to worry about sending plain text over the Internet.

All you need to do is to install the nuget package and then override `CreateTempDataProvider` in your `ControllerBase` class:

```
using BrockAllen.CookieTempData;

namespace myProject.web.Controllers
{
    public class ControllerBase : Controller
    {
        // use CookieTempDataProvider instead of default provider
        protected override ITempDataProvider CreateTempDataProvider()
        {
            return new CookieTempDataProvider();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't use Sessions for this, but Profiles instead. Profiles use cookies to match computers to profiles, etc. The profile key is stored in a cookie, and isn't lost when closing browser etc.

Info here; http://odetocode.com/articles/440.aspx

Answer (score -2):

depends on what kind of data you want to store in the cookie, if you want just to store string, the following code will do:

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("username","sth");
            cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```