# Log visitor data using sessions, or an alternative?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session-state

I don't use session state for anything. I've even disabled it in my `Web.config`, and removed the session module. But, I now need to log visitor data, and don't know how?

I though of doing this:

- re-enable session
- catch new sessions in `void Session_Start(object, EventArgs)` method in `Global.asax`
- log stuff of interest

But I'd prefer not to use session state, unless I need to. I recall that sessions are locked by default, which will slow the pipeline.

*So how do I log visitor data in ASP.NET MVC without session state?*

Comment: What do you mean by `log visitor data`?

Comment: @RubensFarias The usual... IP, referrer, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use an [ActionFilterAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

There a how to on the asp.net/mvc site: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

In summary, add a class like:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class LogVisitorsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var descriptor = filterContext.ActionDescriptor;
        var controller = descriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
        var action = descriptor.ActionName;
        var user = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

        // add your logging here
        log(description, controller, action, user);
    }
}
```

You can pull all sorts of interesting "visitor data" during the `OnActionExecuting`, such as controller/action names (as shown) and the values passed to the action (action parameters).

Then you can either add this to individual actions

```
 [LogVisitors]
 public ActionResult Index()
```

or the controller (or a base controller)

```
 [LogVisitors]
 public class HomeController
```

or to all actions and controllers by adding it to your FilterConfig (which should already exist)

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new LogVisitorsAttribute());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a clever approach. But it would fire for each request. How would I do this only once "per session"? Yes, I know how ironic that sounds! :)

Comment: Actually, if you combine this approach with that I detailed in my answer, then it's a good combination. So I just need to add the cookie logic in your `OnActionExecuting`.

Comment: Swapping cookies for session doesn't seem like a good trade-off.  I don't know specifics but you're increasing bandwidth/client-overhead by reducing server-side processing.   Here's an answer I found that's worth a read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1707263/2181514

Comment: The cookie would be tiny... only contains a timestamp. The overhead would be running this action filter on every rrequest, in comparison the cookie processing is minimal.

Answer (score 1):

> So how do I log visitor data in ASP.NET MVC without session state?

The simple way is, don't log it. Let a 3rd party log it for you. You could use a free service such as [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) or a paid service such as [Hitslink](http://www.hitslink.com/) to monitor everything about your users, and have many charting options to analyze the data later.

Then you don't need to have session state, worry about storage for the data, or have to build your own reporting solution to analyze it.

Comment: If you only need basic data, then it makes sense to roll your own. But I appreciate the comment, which probably applies to many large sites.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of another way, but it's messy:

- intercept in `Application_BeginRequest()` method in `Global.asax`
- compare a cookie to current time
- if >20 minutes then it's a new session, else update cookie with current timestamp
- if new session then perform logging

Cons:

- fires for every request
- reinventing the wheel - this is basically session state!

Pros:

- Lighter than session state
- doesn't lock anything

Hope there's a better way, as this seems messy.